# How can I rewind an audio file with button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

I used audioplayers package in my flutter app.How can I write a logic for rewinding audio?
I share my code with you.
Thanks in advance,

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class AudioController extends GetxController {
  final player = AudioPlayer(); // Create a player
  Rx<bool> isLoading = false.obs;

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    // listen to state play pause,stop
    player.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      //isPlayeing.value true ve ya false olmasi
      isPlaying.value = state == PlayerState.playing;
    });

    //listen audio duration
    player.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
      duration.value = newDuration;
    });

    //listen audio position
    player.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
      position.value = newPosition;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    //player.release();
    //player.dispose();
  }

  var isPlaying = false.obs;
  var duration = Duration.zero.obs;
  var position = Duration.zero.obs;

  Future<void> playOrPause(String url) async {
    isLoading.value = true;
    if (isPlaying.value) {
      isLoading.value = false; //for showing circularprogressindicator
      return await player.pause();
    } else {
      isLoading.value = false;
      return await player.play(UrlSource(url));
    }
  }

  Future<void> pause() async {
    await player.pause();
  }

  void seekForward() {
    player.seek(Duration(milliseconds: 1200));
  }
}
```

I wrote seekForward function.But it does not work.When I play the audio then press the rewind button.Audio position does not change.